# Doubts with serial usb android

Tags: android

I am using this example https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android. to achieve a serial communication of an external device with the Android, the example works, the Android when detecting that an external device is connected to its USB port executes the:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

creating a list of available ports and waiting with the method

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
```

waiting for it to be selected by pressing the port listed to execute the method

```
private void showConsoleActivity(UsbSerialPort port)
```

I need to change this sequence, so that as soon as the Android detects that there is a usb port available automatically run the method

```
private void showConsoleActivity(UsbSerialPort port)
```

my problem is how do I get the parameter "port" so that this method is executed/
Someone can help me?

```
public class DeviceListActivity extends Activity {

private final String TAG = DeviceListActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private UsbManager mUsbManager;
private ListView mListView;

private static final int MESSAGE_REFRESH = 101;
private static final long REFRESH_TIMEOUT_MILLIS = 2500;

private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case MESSAGE_REFRESH:
                refreshDeviceList();
                mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(MESSAGE_REFRESH, REFRESH_TIMEOUT_MILLIS);
                break;
            default:
                super.handleMessage(msg);
                break;
        }
    }

};

private List<UsbSerialPort> mEntries = new ArrayList<UsbSerialPort>();
private ArrayAdapter<UsbSerialPort> mAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mUsbManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.deviceList);

    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<UsbSerialPort>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2, mEntries) {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final TwoLineListItem row;
            if (convertView == null){
                final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                row = (TwoLineListItem) inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, null);
            } else {
                row = (TwoLineListItem) convertView;
            }

            final UsbSerialPort port = mEntries.get(position);
            final UsbSerialDriver driver = port.getDriver();
            final UsbDevice device = driver.getDevice();

            final String title = String.format("Vendor %s Product %s",HexDump.toHexString((short) device.getVendorId()),HexDump.toHexString((short) device.getProductId()));
            row.getText1().setText(title);

            final String subtitle = driver.getClass().getSimpleName();
            row.getText2().setText(subtitle);

            return row;
        }

    };
    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new ListView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Pressed item " + position);
            if (position >= mEntries.size()) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Illegal position.");
                return;
            }
            final UsbSerialPort port = mEntries.get(position);
            showConsoleActivity(port);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MESSAGE_REFRESH);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mHandler.removeMessages(MESSAGE_REFRESH);
}

private void refreshDeviceList() {

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<UsbSerialPort>>() {
        @Override
        protected List<UsbSerialPort> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Refreshing device list ...");
            SystemClock.sleep(1000);

            final List<UsbSerialDriver> drivers = UsbSerialProber.getDefaultProber().findAllDrivers(mUsbManager);

            final List<UsbSerialPort> result = new ArrayList<UsbSerialPort>();
            for (final UsbSerialDriver driver : drivers) {
                final List<UsbSerialPort> ports = driver.getPorts();
                Log.d(TAG, String.format("+ %s: %s port%s",driver, Integer.valueOf(ports.size()), ports.size() == 1 ? "" : "s"));
                result.addAll(ports);
            }

            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<UsbSerialPort> result) {
            mEntries.clear();
            mEntries.addAll(result);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            int usb_ON = 1;
                Log.d(TAG, "Done refreshing, " + mEntries.size() + " entries found.");
          }

    }.execute((Void) null);

    if (mEntries.size() > 0){
        Toast.makeText( this, "Exito", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        final UsbSerialPort port = mEntries.get(int position);
        showConsoleActivity(port);

    }
}

private void showConsoleActivity(UsbSerialPort port) {
    SerialConsoleActivity.show(this, port);
}
```

}